# How can I retrieve the value from a field within a span class?

Tags: java, css, jsoup

I'm writing a web crawler that will store information from Facebook profiles. Information like names, age, interestests, birthdays etc. For this I'm using jsoup.

I've written some code that is working fine but whenever I'm trying to access the birthday element no value is being printed out.

This is in the Facebook source page:

```
<div><span class="accessible_elem">Birthday</span></div>
```

I didn't write it all because this element is withing another `<div>` that is withing another `<div>` etc. 
and this is the code to access the element:

```
//Get the date of birth if one exists
    Elements birthday =doc.select("span.accessible_elem");
    String Birthday=birthday.select("span.accessible_elem").text();
    System.out.println("Birthday: "+Birthday);
```

It works with the other elements but for some reason I can't get a value for this element.

Comment: you do know that scraping is not allowed on facebook, right? the proper way to get user data from facebook is to authorize the user and use the graph api. no one wants you to use his data in any way without his authorization.

Answer (score 0):

You are not allowed to scrape information from facebook.com this way. For more details, see the [Automated Data Collection Terms](https://www.facebook.com/apps/site_scraping_tos_terms.php)
.